# Proving T is a Sub-ring Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is:

$R =\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & b\\ 
  c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

Show that $T =\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & c 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a subring of R

Im not really sure how to prove this with my knowledge of rings.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the definition of a subring (hint: it's a subset of a ring that satisfies some properties)?  You can show that $T$ is a subring of $R$ by showing that $T$ is a subset of $R$ that satisfies those properties.

Comment: I already know the definition of a sub-ring i just dont know where to start in proving T is in R. @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: $R$ is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries.  Is each element of $T$ a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries?  If so, then $T$ is a subset of $R$.

Comment: Oh I see. So as R is the set of 2x2 matricies with real entities, any ring with a 2x2 matrix is a subset of R?? @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: The real question is "Is every element of $T$ also an element of $R$?"  If so, then $T$ is a subset of $R$.  TBH it sounds like it might be helpful for you to brush up on your set theory.  Abstract algebra is a challenging subject, so it it critical to have a solid foundation.

Answer (score 0):

$1.$
Is $T$ non-empty?

$2.$
Is sum of two elements of $T$ in $T$?

$3.$
Is product of two elements of $T$ in $T$?

Comment: Isnt this just proving T is a ring??

Comment: HiHi..$T$ is a subring means $T$ is a ring only with the fact it is a subset of $R$ which it is already

Comment: @OPFragster Yes: A subring is basically a ring that is contained in another ring.  (Just like a subset is a set contained in another set, or a subgroup is a group contained in another group).

Comment: You also want $-x \in T$ for all $x \in T$